# how to use keras and pandas to duplicate similar arrays

Tags: pandas, keras

I have a array from my teacher, he gave me an array like below:

array contains 0,1,none

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, none, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, none,0, 1], [1, 1, none,0, 1, 0, none], [1,1,1,0,none, 0, 0], [1, 1,0, none, 0, 0,1]]
```

---

and asked me to duplicate the array ten times but however each column must have similar percent distribution say each column have no more than 8% percent compared with the origin array.

how should i  achieve  the goal?

Comment: What have you tried already? What do you mean by "column"?

Comment: i have try use nn to predict the similar value, the column i mean is for example, the first column is [1,1,1,1], second column is [1,0,1,1,1]

Comment: Do you want more `arrays` inside your give array or you want to make more arrays like given one? What's your expected output?